# How to display top menu inside main menu?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a top menu, and I want to display it at the bottom of the main menu drop down when in the mobile browser. Like this http://dgmanila.com/

Here's the link: http://mobiletest.me/apple_ipad/2502013

CSS for mobile version:

```
.top-menuv2 ul{ float: none; display: block; clear: both; margin: 10px auto; text-align: center; }
.top-menuv2 li > ul > li{ top: 15px; }
```

Comment: I didn't quite get your question... Could you please rephrase it? Both menu work the same to me :-/

Comment: Yes. What I mean is I want to display the top menu inside of the main menu (at the bottom) when in mobile browser. The first link is the example that I want to achive

Comment: Ah oki... Sorry. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the similar effect as you wanted you might have to do some dirty HTML and CSS hack.

Give a class to this UL, such as `only-desktop`

```
<ul class="only-desktop">
    <li><a href="/testEnvironment/contacts/">Contacts</a></li>
    <li><a href="/testEnvironment/our-partners/">Our Partners</a></li>
    <li><a href="/testEnvironment/careers/">Careers</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/testEnvironment/careers/a-career-with-home-credit/">A Career with Home Credit</a></li>
            <li><a href="/testEnvironment/careers/recruitment-process/">Recruitment Process</a></li>
            <li><a href="/testEnvironment/careers/vacancies/">Vacancies</a></li>
            <li><a href="/testEnvironment/careers/corporate-culture/">Corporate Culture</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and give the css like this,

```
.only-desktop {display:block;}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) /**This width could be anything you want *//
{
.only-desktop {display:none;}
}
```

Then add the same UL right below the nav-menu, but give a different class

```
<ul class="only-mobile">
        <li><a href="/testEnvironment/contacts/">Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="/testEnvironment/our-partners/">Our Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="/testEnvironment/careers/">Careers</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/testEnvironment/careers/a-career-with-home-credit/">A Career with Home Credit</a></li>
                <li><a href="/testEnvironment/careers/recruitment-process/">Recruitment Process</a></li>
                <li><a href="/testEnvironment/careers/vacancies/">Vacancies</a></li>
                <li><a href="/testEnvironment/careers/corporate-culture/">Corporate Culture</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and the css will be,

```
.only-mobile {display:none;}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) 
{
.only-mobile {display:block;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without writing top links twice. Follow the below steps.

> HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"  aria-expanded="false" id="test">Toggle</button>
  </div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

> CSS

```
.container-fluid{
width: 100%;
padding: 10px 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1{
 display: none   
}
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#test{
    float: right;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px){
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1{
 display: block;
  float: left;  
}

#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 ul{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}

#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

#test{
    display: none;
}
.navbar-header{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
}
```

> JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#test").on('click', function(){
    $("#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1").toggle();
  });

})
```

Check the below js fiddle link:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exx830gp/)